# Manipulating string for specific length

Tags: c, string

I need to analyze string and put it centered inside a frame according to width and specific rules.

- There must be at least one space at the beginning and at least one space at the end of row.
- If number of spaces that need to be added is odd, excess space should be added to the right.
- If the whole word cannot fit in the row, word is printed in the next row.
- If the word is longer than row width, word should be split in parts which will be printed in a row in which they can fit complete. Default is to split word in two parts. If that's not possible, word is split proportionally according to the width of row.
- Auxiliary strings are not allowed.

EXAMPLE 1:

```
const char text[]="This is word with four characters";
int width = 20;

********************
*   This is word   *
*    with four     *
*    characters    * 
********************
```

EXAMPLE 2:

```
const char text[]="This word Thyroparathyroidectomized is too long for frame";
int width = 20;

********************
*    This word     * 
*  Thyroparathy-   *
* roidectomized is *
*   too long for   *
*      frame       *
********************
```

EXAMPLE 3:

```
const char text[]="This word Thyroparathyroidectomized is too long for frame";
int width = 10;

**********
*  This  * 
*  word  * 
* Thyro- *
* parat- *
* hyroi- *
* decto- *
* mized  *
* is too *
*  long  *
*   for  *  
* frame  *
**********
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void cut_words(const char *text, int width) {
  char *s = (char *)text;
  // skip leading spaces
  while (*s && *s == ' ')
    s++;
  while (strlen(s) > width) {
    // *s must be nonspace and not EOS
    char *e = s + width - 1;
    // *e is last char that can possibly fit
    // *e cannot be EOS nor can e[1]
    // back up to nonspace if at space
    while (*e == ' ')
      e--;
    // *e is inside or end of word
    if (e[1] != ' ') {
      // not end of word; must be inside
      // back up to prev space
      while (e > s && *e != ' ')
        e--;
      // if e == s then no word break
      // must assume word is longer than width
      if (e == s)
        e = s + width - 1;
      else
        // find end of prev word
        while (e > s && *e == ' ')
          e--;
    }
    // *e is end of word
    int k = e - s + 1;
    printf("* %*.*s *\n", k, k, s);
    s += k;
    while (*s && *s == ' ')
      s++;
  }
  if (*s)
    printf("* %s *\n", s);
}
void framed(const char *text, int width) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < width; i++)
    printf("*");
  printf("\n");
  cut_words(text, width - 4);
  for (i = 0; i < width; i++)
    printf("*");
}
int main() {
  const char text[] = "This is word with four characters";
  int width = 20;
  framed(text, width);
  return 0;
}
```

MY OUTPUTS:

```
********************
* This is word *
* with four *
* characters *
********************

********************
* This word *
* Thyroparathyroid *
* ectomized is too *
* long for frame *
********************

**********
* This *
* word *
* Thyrop *
* arathy *
* roidec *
* tomize *
* d is *
* too *
* long *
* for *
* frame *
**********
```

Could you help me center words in rows?

Comment: You're clearly getting closer (there was a previous edition of this question that has since been deleted).  Your word-splitting isn't adding a hyphen, or allowing for the hyphen taking up space.  When you know what data you're going to put on the line, you need to know how long that data is, and how much padding needs to be added (over and above the asterisk-space at the start and space-asterisk at the end), and split that.  If there are N bytes to add, use N/2 bytes at the beginning and N-(N/2) at the end (which deals with the odd/even issue).

Comment: Note that, as I said before, you have to know which words you're going to add to the line before you start any output (at least, before you add any output other than the starting asterisk-space).

Comment: You could usefully factor the 'print line of stars' code into a function that is called twice.  Yes, it would be tiny — 6 lines of code, I think — but it would include the final newline that your code omits after the second line of stars.  You should expect outputs to end with a newline — it's the sane way of working.

Comment: `strlen(s) > width` will not be the correct test if `s` contains trailing whitespace.

Comment: In the example 2 why is it `*  Thyroparathy-   *` not `* Thyroparathyroi- *`?

Comment: What do you do if the width is too small?  If the width is 5, you can fit one character per line (so a string of single letters separated by spaces as input and gets a 'sane' output), but you can't hyphenate words.  If the width is 6, you can fit one character plus one hyphen per line, which isn't exactly beautiful. Degenerate cases are often key to understanding the code. Consider whether your code behaves with widths longer than the string.  What about consecutive spaces in the middle of the string, or spaces at the start and end?

Comment: @SparKot that word has 25 characters, 25/2=12.5 because we're dividing integer, it's 12. After 12th character dash is put and `\n`. Default is to break words in two parts, if that's not possible it should be proportionally broken into parts

Comment: @JonathanLeffler minimal width in all autotests on our IDE is 8, and maximum is 23, so that's one relief. Now it remains to settle other things.

Comment: Just change `int k = e - s + 1; printf("* %*.*s *\n", k, k, s,);` to `int k = e - s + 1; int b = (width-k)/2; int a = (width-k)/2+(width-k)%2; printf("* %*.*s%*.*s%*.*s *\n", b, b, "###########", k, k, s, a, a, "###########");` and similarily for the other printf.  (replacing the `#` with spaces - I only put them in there so I could see what was happening)

Comment: @JerryJeremiah — using `%*.*s` in the format string means you can use an empty string `""` to supply the data as blanks will be put in the right place.

Comment: it remains to write a dash where needed

Comment: If I edit my question with what you have helped me in comments, question would be closed, so I don't know should I do it. But I can send my improvements through comments, so... Here's my code now, could you help me fix adding dash correctly to this? https://onlinegdb.com/gfDh5eTF_

Comment: If the question is about how to center the words inside the frame then I could write an answer for that.  The hyphenation ould be a completely separate question.

Comment: if you write answer I will accept it, your comment helped me. I will just edit question to be more specific

Comment: Instead of `printf("* %*.*s%*.*s%*.*s *\n", b, b, "", k, k, s, a, a, "");` use `if (lenght_prev_word(s) > width) printf("* %*.*s%*.*s-%*.*s *\n", b, b, "", k, k, s, a-1, a-1, ""); else printf("* %*.*s%*.*s%*.*s *\n", b, b, "", k, k, s, a, a, "");`  Like this: https://onlinegdb.com/5FtEo4yQP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have:

```
int k = e - s + 1;
printf("* %*.*s *\n", k, k, s);
```

and

```
if (*s)
  printf("* %s *\n", s);
```

But that doesn't try to pad the words at all.  To add padding you need to print a certain number of spaces before and after the word.  You can do that the same way you are printing a certain number of characters of the string (`%*.*s`)

You need to replace those bits of code with

```
int k = e - s + 1;
int b = (width-k)/2;
int a = (width-k)/2+(width-k)%2;
printf("* %*.*s%*.*s%*.*s *\n", b, b, "", k, k, s, a, a, "");
```

and

```
if (*s) {
  k = strlen(s);
  b = (width - k) / 2;
  a = (width - k) / 2 + (width - k) % 2;
  printf("* %*.*s%*.*s%*.*s *\n", b, b, "", k, k, s, a, a, "");
}
```

That fixes the centering problem.  But you aren't hyphenating the words - you are just cutting them into pieces.  So you need to account for the hyphen.

To make the portion smaller when the word is going to be cut so there is room for the hyphen you can change

```
// if e == s then no word break
// must assume word is longer than width
if (e == s)
  e = s + width - 1;
```

to

```
// if e == s then no word break
// must assume word is longer than width
if (e == s)
  e = s + width - 2;
```

Then you can change

```
k = e - s + 1;
b = (width - k) / 2;
a = (width - k) / 2 + (width - k) % 2;
printf("* %*.*s%*.*s%*.*s *\n", b, b, "", k, k, s, a, a, "");
```

to

```
k = e - s + 1;
b = (width - k) / 2;
a = (width - k) / 2 + (width - k) % 2;
if (lenght_prev_word(s) > width)
  printf("* %*.*s%*.*s-%*.*s *\n", b, b, "", k, k, s, a-1, a-1, "");
else
  printf("* %*.*s%*.*s%*.*s *\n", b, b, "", k, k, s, a, a, "");
```

And a hyphen will be printed only when the word is longer than the width.

The full program be found at https://onlinegdb.com/4_9eQwA_H